# Python super class / sub class infinite loop

Tags: python, oop, subclass, superclass

I am a student and new to Python. I have the following code:

```
class A:
  ...

  def fit(self, X, y):
     ...
     return self

  def transform(self, X):
    ...
    return transformed_X

  def fit_transform(self, X, y):
    return self.fit(X, y).transform(X)

class B(A):
  ...

  def fit(self, X, y):
    transformed_X = super().fit_transform(X, y)
    ...
```

which I think leads to an infinite loop (`B` calls `fit_transform` in `A` which then calls `fit` in `B` again etc.). Is this correct? How do I get around this? I want the call `super().fit_transform(X, y)` in `B` to return what it would if the object was just of type `A`.

Thank you.

Comment: fit transform only takes an `X` argument in your example. Could you clarify what you would want the output of `B.fit` be (ie the same as `A.fit` or the same as `A.fit_transform`)

Comment: @AntoineRedier Sorry, ```A.fit_transform``` should also take ```y```. I have edited my question. I want ```transformed_X``` in ```B.fit``` to be what ```A.fit_transform``` returns.

Comment: You can certainly do `return A.fit(self, X, y).transform(X)`, but this looks like a flawed design to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out `super().fit_transform(X, y)` is equivalent to `A.fit_transform(self, X, y)` which calls `self.fit` and self is an instance of B. Hence the infinite recursion.

one way to go would be to hard_code the usage of `A.fit` in `A.fit_transform` as such:

```
class A:
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        print("A fit")
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print("A transform")
        return "here we are"

    def fit_transform(self, X, y):
        print("A fit_transsform")
        return A.fit(self, X, y).transform(X)

class B(A):
  

  def fit(self, X, y):
    print("B fit")
    transformed_X = super().fit_transform(X, y)
    return transformed_X
```

which prints:

```
B fit
A fit_transsform
A fit
A transform
'here we are'
```

However this code is very ugly and your classes/methods might not be designed properly (maybe compose rather than inherit since B seems to *use* A rather than *being* an A)